# jquery gzoom how to set default image size to defualt

Tags: jquery, zooming

i am attempting to use jquery gzoom:

```
http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/
```

This is my jquery:

```
 $(".zoom_no_lbox").gzoom({
    sW: 800,
    sH: 500,
    lW: 1600,
    lH: 1000,
    lightbox: true
});
```

This is my image:

```
<div class="zoom zoom_no_lbox" id="zoom02"><img src="uploads/007/pg_0009.jpeg" alt="007" class=" "></div>
```

but as you can see in the gzoom function i have put in the size of the image. However, the images on the page are loaded dynamically and can vary in default length. So how can i set the default to be the default of the image?

Comment: well you can call gzoom on img load event and after that you can set parameters value according to image

Comment: i dont know how to do this, possible to show example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly give your image an id and after that

```
$('#ImageId').load(function(){
$(".zoom_no_lbox").gzoom({
    sW: value,
    sH: value,
    lW: value,
    lH: value,
    lightbox: true
});
});
```

try to set value here by getting attributes of image

Comment: sorry what i need is for the image to be full size and then be able to zoom maybe x4 further into it, your example works, but the image is set to default and the zoom is the same

Comment: can you tell me what is sW,sH,lW,lH

Comment: sorry i dont think the image load is working because of the way the images are being created

Comment: $("#mainContent").html('<h2>' + title + '</h2><br/><div class="zoom zoom_no_lbox" id="zoom02"><img src="' + jpeg + '" alt="' + title + '" class="img" /></div>');

Comment: how do i do it if im loading the images like this?

Comment: call load function after this                          $("#mainContent").html('<h2>' + title + '</h2><br/><div class="zoom zoom_no_lbox" id="zoom02"><img src="' + jpeg + '" alt="' + title + '" class="img" /></div>');

Comment: this just diplays the image at normal size

Comment: can you tell me what is sW,sH,lW,lH

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15329/discussion-between-beginner-and-rahul)