# Reset zoom position when a new image is loaded in div

Tags: jquery, css, image, zooming, reset

The page I am creating currently has a div with an image inside. There are a set of links underneath this image div that, when a new link is clicked, the image in the div changes.

I also have a zooming effect on the image div, so that when the user clicks on the plus/minus symbols, or scrolls with their mouse, they zoom into the image.

The zooming script I am using is this one: http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/

My issue is this: when a new link is clicked, and the image changed, the zoom remains "zoomed in". I am trying to make the zoom reset to completely zoomed out when a new image is  loaded in the div.

Anyone have any ideas?

P.S. I am using the latest Jquery, as well.

Here is a glimpse at my coding.

```
<div id="zoom01" class="zoom minizoompan">
<img class="zoomable" id="SHOWCASEIMG" src="images/image1.jpg">
</div>

<div class="showcase-links">     
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('SHOWCASEIMG').src='images/image1.jpg';return false;">Image 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('SHOWCASEIMG').src='images/image2.jpg';return false;">Image 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('SHOWCASEIMG').src='images/image3.jpg';return false;">Image 3</a>
</div>

<script type= "text/javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        $(function() {
            $("#zoom01").gzoom({
                    sW: 700,
                    sH: 525,
                    lW: 1400,
                    lH: 1050,
                    lightbox : false,
            });
        });
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've solved with a little help ;-)

It's an old plugin, but it seems that someone uses it. With your question I've updated it and now it includes the setZoom method.

:-)

Comment: Many thanks, Giovanni! I have just posted my response in the hopes that it will help others as you have helped me. :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Javascript, but I think you can try doing a 'reset' type deal and use the "onLoad" function in HTML to call a Javascript function that changes the zoom back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="showcase-links">     
     <a class="imageSwap" href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="images/image1.jpg">Image 1</a>
     <a class="imageSwap" href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="images/image1.jpg">Image 1</a>
     <a class="imageSwap" href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="images/image1.jpg">Image 1</a>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".imageSwap".on("click", function() {
     // reset function to set the zoom back to default
     ...

     var imageUrl = $(this).data('link');
     $("#SHOWCASEIMG".attr("src",imageUrl);
});
```

Since I don't know the zooming script, you need to create yourself a function that resets the zoom.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that helps me, then.

Comment: Afraid to do some work yourself? Or try Google... [first hit on Google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949780/jquery-gzoom-how-to-set-default-image-size-to-defualt)

Comment: I have been searching Google all day, and only came here to ask when I felt I had run out of options. There was no need to insult my work ethic.

Answer (score 0):

I was at last able to contact the original creator of the zoom script I was using, and he was kind enough to update the script to allow for the zoom to be reset. However, there was a issue that was quickly resolved between the two of us (but mostly him, truth be told, since I'm still a Javascript newbie). I told him I would update this post in case anyone came along with the same issue as me.

[http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/][1]

The new JS file handles the zoom function just fine, but it is in the page itself that the changes need to be made.

This is what I had originally.

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    $(function() {
        $("#zoom01").gzoom({
                sW: 700,
                sH: 525,
                lW: 1400,
                lH: 1050,
                lightbox : false,
        });
    });
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

The new script looks like this:

```
 <script type= "text/javascript">
      /*<![CDATA[*/
      $(function() {
          $zoom = $("#zoom01").gzoom({
                sW: 700,
                sH: 525,
                lW: 2000,
                lH: 1500, 
                lightbox : false
         });
      });
      /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

The part that has changed is this:

```
$zoom = $("#zoom01").gzoom({
```

The issue that arose after the script was changed to allow for resetting the Zoom came when more than one $zoom was being called to accommodate for images of different sizes. That was done using this javascript language:

```
 $('#select1, #select2, #select3, #select4, #select5, #select6').click(function() {
                $('#subContainer1').show();                               
                $('#subContainer2').hide();
                $zoom.setZoom(0);
            });

            $('#select7, #select8').click(function() {
                $('#subContainer1').hide();                                   
                $('#subContainer2').show();
                $zoom2.setZoom(0);
            });
        });
```

In order to resolve this, I changed the name for each $zoom being called:

```
 <script type= "text/javascript">
      /*<![CDATA[*/
        $(function() {
            $zoom = $("#zoom01").gzoom({
                sW: 700,
                sH: 525,
                lW: 2000,
                lH: 1500, 
                lightbox : false
            });
            $zoom2 = $("#zoom02").gzoom({
                sW: 700,
                sH: 350,
                lW: 2000,
                lH: 1000, 
                lightbox : false
            });
            $('#select1, #select2, #select3, #select4, #select5, #select6').click(function() {
                $('#subContainer1').show();                               
                $('#subContainer2').hide();
                $zoom.setZoom(0);
            });

            $('#select7, #select8').click(function() {
                $('#subContainer1').hide();                                   
                $('#subContainer2').show();
                $zoom2.setZoom(0);
            });
        });
      /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

Along with the script changing to the final version above, the HTML was also changed to accommodate for different image sizes.

```
<div id="zoom01" class="zoom minizoompan"><img class="zoomable" id="SHOWCASEIMG" src="images/image1.jpg"></div>

<div id="zoom02" class="zoom minizoompan"><img class="zoomable" id="SHOWCASEIMG2" src="images/image2.jpg"></div>

<a href="#" id="select1" onclick="document.getElementById('SHOWCASEIMG').src='image1.jpg';return false;">Image 1</a> 
<a href="#" id="select7" onclick="document.getElementById('SHOWCASEIMG2').src='image2.jpg';return false;">Image 2</a>
```

The id values SHOWCASEIMG and SHOWCASEIMG2 change the image according to which zoom div is needed: zoom01 or zoom02. The id values 'select1' and 'select7' are used to designate what size the zoom box needs to be.

Many thanks to Giovanni for his invaluable help!